# Pass data from child to parent when child is rendered through ng-template

Tags: angular, viewchild, ng-template

I am using `@ViewChild` to create a child component, through a template reference variable. I would like to pass data from the dynamically created child to its parent, in any way, but preferably using the `@Output` decorator.

Is this possible in any manner?

**Parent.html**

```
<ng-template #childComponent></ng-template>
```

**Parent.ts**

```
@ViewChild("childComponent", { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
  myChildComponent: ViewContainerRef;
  componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

createComponent() {
  const myChildComponentRef = this.myChildComponent;
  this.componentRef = myChildComponentRef.createComponent(ChildComponent);
  this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

**Child.html**

```
<div class="table-container">
  Some table here, populated by data from a server response
</div>
```

**Child.ts**

```
@Output() data = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

constructor() { }

outputData() {
  this.data.emit(serverResponse);
}
```

I have used `@Output` before and I am aware that the parent's method should be bound to the child's event, within the child's selector in the parent's template. Since I do not have the child's selector because of the ng-template, I cannot think of good way to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event emitters are just glorified observables.

When you create your child component, you can then call

```js
this.componentRef.data.subscribe(...);
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks too !

Comment: I apologize for the late feedback. You're absolutely right. I am accepting your answer.